# Flowbite Datepicker not using input value

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs3, flowbite

I got a very basic setup for a datepicker:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite'
import Datepicker from 'flowbite-datepicker/Datepicker';

const datepickerRef = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
    initFlowbite();

    new Datepicker(datepickerRef.value); 
})

const date = ref('');
</script>

<template>
<div class="relative max-w-sm">
  <input ref="datepickerRef" datepicker v-model="date" type="text"><br>
  {{ date }}
</div>
</template>
```

The v-model binding is not working. Is datepicker not using the value and if true, what do I need to do to get the reactive value?